# Apply class to svg inside a div

Tags: html, css

My code is shown below. However, nothing is applied to the svg. What is the best way to resolve this?

[image]

```
.icon {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}

.icon > svg {
    fill: brown;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inline style `fill="none"`, `width="37"` and `height="36"` from svg.

Comment: how about width height though?

Comment: I have updated the question now after removing all parameters you mentioned. but no luck

Answer (score 1):

A trick I use is to give a `color` property to the parent element, in this case `.icon` and have the svg css as `fill: currentColor`

```
.icon {
  color: brown;
  /* Rest of your code */
}

.icon > svg {
  fill: currentColor;
  /* Rest of your code */
}
```

More details [here](https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/)

Comment: nope, still nothing.